# Form Herdado vem sem opção de edição nele todo. Uso C# e VS 2017

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando crio o Form2 Herdado do Form1, não consigo editar nada nele. Claro que o cadeado na parte esquerda superior tem algo a ver, mas como posso resolver essa situação?

Segue a imagem pra melhor entendimento. Obrigado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, considere aceitar uma das respostas se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que possam melhorá-la.

Answer (score 1):

No `form` pai, vá no controle que deseja que seja alterado, na propriedade `modifiers`, coloque `public`.

Answer (score 1):

O recurso [`Lock Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/80xxxf69(v=vs.110).aspx) foi ativado em seu formulário.

Ao ativar esta opção, todos os controles ficaram marcados com este cardeado, indicando que **não poderá movê-los ou redimensioná-los**.

Você poderá bloquear/desbloquear controles individualmente, ou todos simultaneamente.

**Ativação/desativação individual**

- Selecione um controle, e em suas propriedade, altere a opção Locked (Bloqueado).

**Ativação/desativação geral**

- Para ativar/desativar todos os controles use: Menu Format (Formatar) > Lock Controls (Bloqueio de Controles)

Answer (score -2):

Botão direito no formulário -> Lock Controls